# Sentencia equivalente al "&O" de Basic en C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Estoy implementando un programa de conversión de números de Visual Basic.Net a C#.
Este es el código original (funcionado correctamente) que convierte un número de octal a binario

```
Public Function OctToBin(ByVal OctStr As String) As String     
    Dim NumBin As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 0
    
    OctStr = CInt("&O" + OctStr)
    
    Do
        If CBool(CLng(OctStr) And CLng(Math.Pow(2,i))) Then
            NumBin = "1" & NumBin
        Else
            NumBin = "0" & NumBin
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Math.Pow(2 , i) > CInt(OctStr)
    Return NumBin
End Function
```

En C# tengo el siguiente código:

```
    public string OctToBin(string OctStr)
    {
        string NumBin = "";
        int i;

        i = 0;
        
        OctStr = Convert.ToInt64("&O" + OctStr);
        
        do
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(System.Convert.ToInt64(OctStr) & System.Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(2, i))))
                NumBin = "1" + NumBin;
            else
                NumBin = "0" + NumBin;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        while (!(Math.Pow(2, i) > System.Convert.ToDouble(OctStr)));
        return NumBin;
    }
```

Pero marca error en la línea:

```
OctStr = Convert.ToInt64("&O" + OctStr);
```

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'long' en 'string'
> (CS0029)

Estoy siguiendo la idea de Visual Basic.NET

Comment: porque tratas de convertir un numero en string sin usar el metodo tostring?

Comment: ¿Dónde quiero convertir un número a string? La variable numero está definida como string.

Comment: por eso mismo, queres convertir un Int64 y eso se lo queres pasar a un string que seria OctStr .

Comment: Me estoy guiando por lo que está en Basic, pero son lenguajes distintos.

Comment: en visual basic la conversion es implicita, la hace automaticamente... en c#, la conversion la tenes que hacer manual, usando el metodo ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que en C# no hay una manera de representar un numero octal, por medio de un prefijo, te recomiendo que uses la sobre carga del método Convert.ToInt64(), para pasarle como parámetro la base con la que estas trabajando, el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
OctStr = Convert.ToInt64(OctStr,8).ToString();
```

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Si, me funcionó